# Google Chrome bug in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Is it just me or is there a right-click bug for Chrome in OS X Lion? I first noticed that double finger tapping the trackpad didn't show any menu when in chrome (either on a link or on anything).

I thought it was a problem with my trackpad settings in OS X Lion but I checked the Finder and Firefox and right-clicking DOES work. Was it broken together with other mouse gestures in OS X Lion?

Is there a current fix for this?

Comment: Works for me. I tried it on the Google homepage.

Comment: No issue at all on my side also. Try reinstalling chrome.

Comment: hmm tried reinstalling chrome and it still doesn't work though(deleted it from apps then installed a new one)

Comment: im testing it out now and double tapping(or two right clicks with the mouse) with 2 fingers does the job. but why does it have to be a double tap? in ff and finder(and any other app) a single double finger tap is enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was one of my plugins: Mouse gestures. I was wondering why it was working on my speed dials page(the right click) and when I turned off gestures, right click suddenly worked.

Comment: If this is the solution, even if it's your own answer, you should still mark it as the answer.

Comment: yeah, but i just asked it yesterday so i still have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue, it was "Scrollbar Anywhere" extension in my case.